# Google Sheets Query: Making the selected column depend on formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I would like to use a normal `QUERY` with `where` operating in the usual way `where A = 'Speed'` but with the selected column being determined based on a formula. Specifically, I want to return only the column that has a certain user-determined number in row 1. Row 1 has numbers from the range 4 to 10 without duplicates but in a variable order.

My sample data is:

```
         A          B        C                  D        E  
-----------------------------------------------------------------
   1 | -----        5        6                  7        8
   2 | Speed        Slow     Fair               Medium   Fast  
   3 | Comfort      Bad      Barely acceptable  Bla      Bla,bla                
   4 | Reliability  Low      Acceptable         Blabla   Blablabla
```

The query should look something like:

```
=QUERY('Sheetname'!A1:E; "Select xxx where A = 'Speed')
```

I'm looking for what I should put in place of xxx depending on the values of row 1.

Comment: Denoting the content of the sheet at row i and column j as S(i,j), you want to return all the S(i,j) where i satisfies: S(i,A)="Speed" and j satisfies S(1,j)=N. N can vary from 4...10. Correct? If that's the case we should probably rewrite the question to make that clearer.

Comment: Cheers for the edits @CorneliusRoemer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determine column alphabet letter as follows: `=char(64+MATCH(N,1:1,0))` where you substitute the number you want for N=4,5...10.

Then add that to the query string formulaically. Done:

`=QUERY(A1:D4,"select "&char(64+MATCH(5,1:1,0))&" where A = 'Speed'")`

Important limitation for generalisations: this only works for column index up to 27, because it can't form column names like `AA` etc.

Comment: Great help! Thanks! :-)