# Select All Columns Where Cell In Columns Contain A Word - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am looking for a query formula that will allow me to select all columns (entire column) that contain a specific word within the column.

You can see a test sheet here:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aP7sDTf0xlxQFK51wiswiXcIMKvUNL_3hpi0qhDCvx4/edit#gid=0

For this example, I would like a query that would scan Sheet1 and select all columns that contain the words "Adam". This would select Columns A-D.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, your test sheet is not public, can you change the sharing settings (view)

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions offered? Did any of them work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I believe the `FILTER` function would be a much better fit than the `QUERY` *(which becomes quite convoluted)*.

Please try the following formula:

```
=FILTER(A1:I,A1:I1="Adam")
```

> ***Pro Tip***

*Two significant differences of `FILTER` vs `QUERY` is that using the `FILTER` function you get to "transfer/preserve" both the numbers' original formatting as well as the empty rows.*

[image: formatting and empty rows transfer through the filter function]

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer : This is maybe not the most efficient way to do it, but more something like an intuition on how to do it.

Last try :

```
=textjoin(",",true,
ArrayFormula(char(64+unique(transpose((split(textjoin(",",true,
ArrayFormula(if(REGEXMATCH(A1:Z100,"Adam"),COLUMN(A1:Z100),))),",")))
))
))
```

---

Use this formula in your query like this :
`=query( range , "Select "& (the formula) & " Where [..]")`

---

Credit to [this answer (how to get a column's address)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/135613/222777)